I was deploying the application on eks using gitlab
i was deploying an application on eks using gitlab cicd but facing the isuue related to docker unable to coonect with the host
iables:
DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://localhost:2375"
DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" # Disable TLS for Docker-in-Docker
services:

name: docker:24.0.5-dind
alias: docker
command:

--host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
--host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
--tls=false



this is the script which i am using
